# How to run a Python program on Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, python

I made a Python program for a client, and he wants the python program to run on Ubuntu server. I am not familiar at all with Linux.

I do not understand, what he mean by "Ubuntu Server". Does he mean, he has a website that runs on Ubuntu server? He needs the program ready in next few hours, I asked him for clarification on this thing, but he is probably sleeping, and I need to make the project ready as soon as possible.

Comment: Probably `python /path/to/python/script.py`.

Comment: Ubuntu Server is a flavor of stock Ubuntu without any GUI, and with some extra server packages. The admin communicates with the server using shell only, usually over an ssh connection. It can *serve* webpages and graphical environments to clients. Python 3 is already included on all flavors of Ubuntu. Python 2 is already included on most flavors, and is trivially added on the rest.

Comment: Hey, he said He don't want the script to run on his pc. If not in PC, how will he access the script?? Via a website right? I don't understand :/ Sorry

Comment: ohh that makes sense @user535733 thanks  a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are several different versions of `python`:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python* 
/usr/bin/python  /usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.5  /usr/bin/python3.5m  /usr/bin/python3m  /usr/bin/pythontex  /usr/bin/pythontex3
```

Pick the one you want, I'll use `/usr/bin/python` for the example. Make the 1st line of your script be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```